# Unhashable type: 'set' Error

Tags: python, python-3.x, set

I'm trying to find the common values of two keys in a dictionary and have it return as a set. But when I want to change a list back into a set (as seen on the last line of my code) it produces the error `"Unhashable type"`. I am aware of what this error means, but I unfortunately do not know how to fix it in this case.

```
def values_in_common(dict, key1, key2):
a = []
b = []
for i, e in dict.items():
    if i == key1:
        a.append(e)
    if i == key2:
        b.append(e)
x = []
for i in a:
    if i in b:
        x.append(i)
return set(x)
```

Comment: One of the items of the list is an un-hashable type (e.g `list`, `dict`). Use `print(x)` to find out which.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what your code is actually supposed to do, but my understanding is that:

```
a = dict.get(key1) or []
b = dict.get(key2) or []
```

So whatever values are stored in key1 and key2, or empty lists if there is no appropriate key in the dictionary.

Then, you want to find common elements in a and b, so something like:

```
return set(a) & set(b)
```

Answering your question, I do not think there is a problem with the code you posted, but with arguments you pass to the function.